# Which way is better to define type traits or behavior?

Tags: c++, templates, traits

There are two ways to define type traits or behavior in template programming.

One is to define inside the class

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef ... DialogType;
    static string type() {...}
    ...
};
```

The other one is defined outside the class

```
class MyClass {...};

template<class T> struct Dialog;
template<> struct Dialog<MyClass> { typedef ... Type;}


template<class T> string type();
template<> string type<MyClass>() { ... }
```

Which way is better and why> Or is there is any other better way?

Comment: There is no "better" way. The first is concise and I prefer it if it works, but sometimes there are reasons why you can't use it and you have to use the second approach or some other approach.

Comment: @DanielFrey for template-metaprogramming, one trait per type property  scales a lot better than a "blob" of nested types because not all the unused nested types have to be parsed.

Comment: @TemplateRex Sure, but that's exactly the point: "For template metaprogramming". And even for TMP, sometimes you want other solutions. My point is, that there is no one-size-fits-all solution and hence there is no *generally* "better" solution.

Answer (score 1):

For "regular" template programming, it is best to combine whatever is required to define your **domain abstraction**. This is best done using the design principles (SOLID etc.) that you use with regular classes. However, for template classes you will typically also try to factor out template independent code in a non-template base class (in order to avoid code bloat).

For metaprogramming purposes, the Boost.MPL library exclusively uses one nested type per class for two reasons (they even go as far as to call multiple types per trait a "blob" anti-pattern):

1. it is more efficient, because whenever one nested type is accessed, the class instantiation will not lead to a lot of unnecessary parsing of other unused nested types
2. it is easier to compose meta functions when having a single "return type"

Comment: What does "one nested type per class" mean? Is it the second way (outside the class) I showed? Tanks.

Comment: @user1899020 yes, the 2nd one defines a separate class template per trait, instead of a bunch of nested types inside of each class.